# Identifying d3d9 member functions

Tags: c++, directx

Is there a way to identify (Direct-X) member functions?

I'm writing a simple debugger and I need the address of a member function to place a breakpoint on it (INT3/0xCC).

Currently I'm trying to identify the functions by doing:

```
std::unordered_map<void*, const char*> hookMap {
    {(void*)&IDirect3D9::QueryInterface, "IDirect3D9::QueryInterface"},
};
```

but I cannot cast a member function to a void pointer. The other idea I thought of is using the VTable indexes and addresses from there instead. Any better ideas?